# Handling Error Thrown by Observable

Tags: angular, observable

The following HTML/JS reads countries from a local JSON files and provides the list to a dropdown:

```js
export interface Country {
  code: string;
  name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class CountriesService {
  private url = '/assets/data/countries.json';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getCountries(): Observable < Country[] > {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return Observable.throw(err);
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control custom-select" formControlName="country">
     <option value="" disabled selected hidden translate>Select Country</option>
     <option *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async" value="{{country.code}}">{{country.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

What happens if an error is thrown in the `getCountries()` function, where am I supposed to catch it and display a user-friendly message?

Note: I'm using the `async` pipe in the component HTML

Comment: You can handle it in the `catch` block you have there. Example: Add a new component field named `fatalErrorMessage` and populate that in the `catch` and display it in your template if there is a value using `*ngIf="fatalErrorMessage"`. What you do or display depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the `catch` block is in the service, not the component.

Comment: Since the error is rethrown it will traverse up the stack. What do you actualy want is a error handler method that is missing.

Comment: Ah! And where should this error handler method be? Can it be in the component or does it have to be a global instance of `ErrorHandler` provided in my module, and if it's the latter, then how do I "bubble" it back into the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it in the catch block at the point you subscribe to `getCountries`. Example: Add a new component field named fatalErrorMessage and populate that in the catch and display it in your template if there is a value using *ngIf="fatalErrorMessage". What you do or display depends on your requirements.

I made a guess on the logic of your component.

```
fatalError:string = null;
ngOnInit(){
    this.countries$ = this.countryService.getCountries().catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.fatalError = "Countries could not be loaded";
        return Observable.of([]); // return empty array
      });
}
```

Template code:

```
<p *ngIf="fatalError">An unexpected error has occurred: {{fatalError}}</p>
<select class="form-control custom-select" formControlName="country">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden translate>Select Country</option>
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async" value="{{country.code}}">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean, and so remove the catch from the service entirely?

Comment: @Sammy - if it adds no value to the call chain you could remove it as any error would be caught in the catch of the component.

Comment: Well, if I do *not* remove it, it will never be caught in the component though!

Comment: @Sammy - the code in your service (from your question) re-throws it so it would still be caught (again) by the component (`Observable.throw(err)`)

Comment: Of course, I'm stupid. Yes, in this case I would be logging to sentry.io (for example) in the service and then actually displaying the error in the component. Thank you!